# Renaming tags while converting a Mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, tags, rename

I have a Mercurial repository and want only a subset from its content in a new Mercurial repository. I know how to do this using the [Convert Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial) with a filemap file.

However, I also like to filter the tags, i.e. only keep one specific to the files I like to include. I'm would be able to name all these tags and would also like to rename them. In other words I would need a tagmap feature as well.

I'm aware I just could exclude `.hgtags` and then add all tags manually or how to [rename tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568693/mercurial-how-to-change-name-of-a-tag), but I actually like to keep the original tagging dates and revisions, so the converted repository looks "authentic".

Any ideas how to do this? I wouldn't mind writing some Python code as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if how the order is preserved, but you can specify the date you want the tag recorded as when you create a tag with -d or --date? It doesn't solve exactly the revision it was put in, but it does let you set the date to what you want.

Comment: @TrentonSchulz: Thanks. I know about `--date` and used it before. This is actual my backup plan.

Comment: Could you combine that with a convert sorted by date instead of by branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature does not exist today, as you've found out. Writing it will be a fun little exercise :-) You should start with the source for the `hg` sink and change the [`_rewritetags` function](http://selenic.com/hg/file/tip/hgext/convert/hg.py#l120). It parses the `data` (the content of the `.hgtags` file for the changeset that's currently being converted) and rewrites the changeset hashes to match the new hashes.

This is your opportunity to rewrite or exclude tags! I modified the file like this to exclude tags below version 2.0 and to rewrite them slightly:

```
def _rewritetags(self, source, revmap, data):
    def keep(tag):
        try:
            version = map(int, tag.split('.'))
            return version >= [2, 0]
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def rename(tag):
        return tag + "-partial"

    fp = cStringIO.StringIO()
    for line in data.splitlines():
        s = line.split(' ', 1)
        if len(s) != 2:
            continue
        if not keep(s[1]):
            continue
        revid = revmap.get(source.lookuprev(s[0]))
        if not revid:
            continue
        fp.write('%s %s\n' % (revid, rename(s[1])))
    return fp.getvalue()
```

For testing, I also change `self.filemapmode` to `True` unconditionally. Otherwise, `convert` wont detect and filter out empty commits. Since you use a filemap already, you should be fine.

Finally, strip the extra "update tags" changeset added by convert and you'll have a nice history again.