# hg clone tag or branch

Tags: windows, version-control, mercurial, redhat

We are using the following command to clone repositories;

```
hg clone -u v1.0 \\server\abc\def my_repo
```

If the repository contains both a tag and branch that is named "v1.0" then the command will update to the tag revision. In this situation, how can we force the hg clone command to select the branch? We do not want to use the `--branch` option because some repositories may only contain the tag and not the branch.

Tried various combinations of this command (with single and double quotes) and they all reported "unknown revision"

```
hg clone -u branch(v1.0) \\server\abc\def my_repo
hg clone -u "branch(v1.0)" \\server\abc\def my_repo
hg clone -u 'branch(v1.0)' \\server\abc\def my_repo
```

Does hg clone support using revset?

Please advise :-)

Comment: Why not just do the update as a separate command? hg update "branch(v1.0)" or hg update "tag(v1.0)"

Comment: The hg clone command is executed as part of a set of scripts which then must be updated. The "v1.0" string is part of a configuration file which also must be updated. So your suggestion would require a bigger change to our current setup.

Comment: Maybe you should rename all the conflicting tags, and then there is no problem? https://stackoverflow.com/q/7568693/3195477

Comment: I agree that is a possible solution. In general I would like to know if this issue can be solved using hg clone command.

Comment: Anyway, you **must** change a piece of code around `hg clone` and wrap it into *some logic*. Read `hg help id`, note final sentence "Returns 0 if successful" and possibility to use revsets in `-r` option for `hg id`